Dynamic Pull Down with MOSFET


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Hello everyone. I'm going crazy prototyping, calculating and banging my head against MOSFETs, can you help me?
I have a circuit with a load that needs to be turned on and off programmatically. The load is light, it's only 8V4 with a maximum of 20ma and I can't leave it constantly connected to 8V4 because it causes malfunctions. I'm trying to create a circuit to switch the VCC of the load, leaving it constantly connected to GND.
I'm using an ESP32 with 3V3 GPIOs.
To control the ON-OFF of the VCC of the load, I need to use the AO3401 P-channel MOSFET with Vgs(th) of -1.3V, that is, the voltage at the gate needs to be very close to the voltage at the source to close the current flow. That's why I made a pull-up (R3) between the source and the gate to ensure that the voltage at both points is the same and with that the MOSFET "turns off" and cuts off the power supply to the load. It is because of this Vgs(th) so close to the source that I cannot "turn off" the MOSFET with the 3V3 from the ESP32.
To lower the voltage at the gate of this MOSFET (A03401), I used another MOSFET, the AO3400 of the N-Channel type with Vgs(th) of 1.45V, that is, the ESP32 GPIO with 3V3 is more than enough to "turn on" this MOSFET and connect GND to the gate of the MOSFET that controls the load. The idea is that this MOSFET controlled by the ESP32 acts as a pull-down to lower the voltage that is under the gate of the AO3401 and thus "turn on" the load. The expectation is that the voltage will reach close to 0V at the gate of the AO3401 and remain at a negative voltage in relation to the source, this would make the AO3401 "turn on" and connect the source to the drain, powering the load.
I used a pull-down resistor (R2) on the GPIO port because when the ESP32 goes into deep sleep, the GPIO starts to have voltage fluctuations.
I used a resistor (R1) between the AO3400 gate and the GPIO to protect the ESP32 port.
I thought I had thought everything right, but in practice it is not working. The voltage on the AO3401 gate does not drop more than a few millivolts and so my load never turns off. What could be wrong?

I don't see anything wrong with your schematic (except putting the ground of the NFET source at the top, which is annoying).  Check your polarities and connections, maybe check the integrity of the FETs with an ohmmeter (gate to source, drain to source)..

Which pin on the ESP32 are you using to control the MOSFETs and how did you define that pin in your program/sketch?

Your approach seems dubious - do you have to switch the devices VCC? In other words, can you leave VCC common and switch the device's ground?

@MOSFET As I said, I can't leave the VCC connected.

@EdinFifić It can be any digital pin configured as output in the code setup. For example, it can be GPIO 13.

@GustavoQuirino The reason I ask is because some pins may have other functions which make them behave erratically, especially during sleep, shutdown or wake-up, so avoiding them is recommended. Is your pin default state is defined as floating or pull-up? That will affect your desired results and give you problems.

@GustavoQuirino Here is a link to a page that tells you which pins are safe on ESP32: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-pinout-reference-gpios/

Did you connect the grounds on your schematic with the ESP32 ground?

@EdinFifić I'm using the Arduino framework and I'm not setting it as pull up, just changing it between HIGH and LOW. However, I have a pull down resistor on the GPIO just to ensure a low level when I turn off the pin or the ESP32 goes into deep sleep.

@bobflux yes, i connected.

After much investigation and research, I discovered that I was damaging the MOSFETs with static electricity. I started to be more careful not to damage them and the problem was solved. There was nothing wrong with the circuit. I didn't know that the MOSFET is so sensitive to electrostatic discharge.

The bad news is there's absolutely nothing wrong with this design, at least nothing that would cause it to fail with a purely resistive load:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you're powering a relay coil, or any kind of inductive load, then you'll probably fry Q2 eventually, after a few on-off cycles. You should mitigate that risk with a diode, D1 here:

simulate this circuit
You say that node X never drops more than a few millivolts, and that this causes the load to be permanently on. That makes no sense, since to turn on Q2, \$V_X<<8.4V\$. If X is stuck at +8.4V, the load should be off. However, you claim that the load is always on, regardless of \$V_{IN}\$, suggesting that the culprit is Q2.
Are you sure that Q2 isn't damaged? ESD from bad handling can kill a MOSFET before you even get it out of the packet it came in, and an inductive load (without D1) can kill it too. Such a failure can cause the gate to be physically fused with the channel, causing gate potential to be +8.4V always. It could also cause a lot more current through Q1 than you expect, killing that too. Happily you protected the MCU with R1.
Some other ideas: are you sure that

you haven't swapped source and drain of Q2? There's a parasitic diode between those terminals (the so-called "body diode") that would permanently conduct, regardless of Q2's \$V_{GS}\$. Usually we aim to keep that diode reverse biased, so it doesn't conduct.

R3 really is 10kΩ and not ridiculously small, like 10Ω?

Potential \$V_{Y}\$ at Q1's gate actually goes between 0V and +3.3V?



I've redrawn the circuit in the question :)

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The universe and I salute you! There may be a special place in purgatory reserved for people who draw ground symbols upside-down. If ever I did that, I beg forgiveness.

I'm pretty sure my MOSFETs are damaged. For a moment, only one worked for a few minutes, I even thought I had solved the mystery but then it stopped working. R3 is 10KΩ yes, if it were zero or as low as 10Ω, the n-channel MOSFET would burn out with the current entering the drain towards the source when activated (I tested this in practice). My load is an LDO to regulate to a lower voltage and power a small LORA radio.

So you can't leave the VCC connected. Fine. Try this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This will work with any P-CH MOSFET (almost). Not just those weird ultra-low Vgs types.

Personally, I would make the R2 10kΩ, and R1 and R3 100kΩ, to minimize power consumption while not affecting functionality.


I thought I had thought everything right, but in practice it is not working.

Most likely, you got the pinouts of the mosfets wrong. Check connections on the breadboard. Better yet, post a clear photo of your breadboard.
Maybe the mosfets are bad? Here's how to check. First, try pulling M1's gate down with a 1k resistor. Does it go down to ≈0.8V as shown? Does the load turn on? If the gate is stuck at supply voltage, then the mosfet is blown or it is not connected properly.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Once you can get that simple circuit to control the load properly, keep it on the breadboard, and add M2 in a separate circuit to troubleshoot it - do not interconnect M1 and M2!

simulate this circuit
Once this 2nd test circuit gets working, connect M2 OUT to M1's gate, remove the duplicate R3, and it should all work correctly then.

Another way to design such a circuit would be to use a common-base switch in place of M2:

simulate this circuit
R1-R2 establish the threshold voltage for Q1. When GPIO is about a diode drop below that threshold, Q1 turns on, current flows through R3 and Q1, the gate is pulled low, and the load turns on.
The base is pulled down to about 0.7V at this point, so a part of the current that has flown through R2 into the ground is now flowing into the GPIO pin.
When GPIO is above the threshold, Q1 turns off, and R3 pulls the gate up to supply voltage, turning the load off.
R1 and R2 are fairly large - the common-base circuit does have current gain even though it has no voltage gain.
D1 is optional to protect Q1's B-E junction from abuse. It may be helpful on the breadboard, but not in the final circuit.

Thank you, will you perform the tests with the MOSFETs I used to see if they are damaged. Is it very easy to damage them?
I have already manufactured the PCBs, it is no longer a protoboard. The resistors are of the 0603 package and the MOSFETs are SOT 23-3. It is a bit confusing to take a print screen of the layout but I have already checked the tracks countless times and they are completely in accordance with the schematic. I am almost convinced that my MOSFETs are damaged.
